# How to remove build warnings from Angular when adding path to tsconfig compilerOptions?

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs, monorepo

I have a monorepo with an Angular 16 application and a NestJS backend. I need them to share some things like enums and interfaces, so I am following [this guide](https://alpharder.medium.com/reusing-code-at-angular-nest-monorepo-oversimplified-f59080e4fa42) which has been helpful.

My folder structure is like this:

```txt
my-repo/
 + ng-ui/
 | | src/ (folder w/ app code)
 | | tsconfig.json
 | | tsconfig.app.json
 | | tsconfig.spec.json
 | | (etc...)
 + nest-api/
 | | src/ (folder w/ app code)
 | | tsconfig.json
 | | tsconfig.build.json
 | | (etc...)
 + monorepo-shared/
 | + enums/
 | | | *.enum.ts files
 | + interfaces/
 | | | *.interface.ts files
```

Interface & enums are moved to the shared folder, and I added the following to my **both** my NestJS and Angular applications `tsconfig.json` file, and then restructure my code in those apps to reference the shared files.

```json
"paths": {
  "@monorepo-shared/enums": ["../monorepo-shared/enums/index"]
}
```

When I build the NestJS app, everything works with no problems at all.

When I build the Angular app, everything works but I get these warnings

```txt
Warning: C:/Users/me/my-repo/ng-ui/src/environments/environment.development.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

Warning: C:/Users/me/my-repo/ng-ui/src/environments/environment.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.
```

I find that strange since `tsconfig.app.json` specifically includes these files. This file is untouched and is how Angular created it when I made the app.

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app"
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/environments/*.ts"]
}
```

How can I remove these warnings when I build?